# Does Twitter streaming api detect plurals?

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Does the twitter streaming api return plural words? 
For example, if I query for 'bike', would the returned tweets include 'bikes'? or include 'dutchbike'? or 'bikelane'?

Comment: this seems like something you could easily test...

Comment: already tested, yet I want an answer for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a definitive answer in the Twitter docs. Read the description of the `track` parameter here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters.

The answer is that when you filter for a word such as "bike" you will get tweets with any form of "bike" (case insensitive). So, all your examples would be included.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: Testing on API confirms this is not correct. Plurals are not caught in singular queries.

Comment: It works for me. What request and parameters are you using?